# Anaconda - Conda update error - PermissionError: [WinError 5]

Tags: permissions, anaconda, conda, updates

I have tried to update Anaconda by running `conda update conda`, but I'm get the following error message:

```bash
(base) C:\>conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): | Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\baffi\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 113, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\baffi\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5]
```

My Anaconda is newly installed for me, not for all users. I ran conda prompt as administrator. I can't run `conda update --all` without this error message either.

I have Anaconda Navigator error too, but I expect to solve this via conda update.

I would like to update my Anaconda and my packages without any error.